# Add git tags based on commit time

Tags: git, msysgit, git-tag

Is there any way to tag a git repository based on the commit time?

For example, if I have the release time, I want to tag all the repositories used in the release as of the release time. The main issue is that tagging may happen retroactively a few hours after release.

My repository is on a Windows XP system and I'm using msysgit to access git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a script that uses the [`--before` option to `git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to get the last commit in a branch before the release timestamp, and then tag that commit.

```
git rev-list -n 1 --before=<timestamp> master
```